# How do I set the value of a hidden form element using form_set_value()?

Tags: forms, 8

When validating a form, I need to set the value of a hidden form element. I tried using this code, but it didn't work.

```php
\Drupal::formBuilder()->setValue($form['maintenance_type'], 'R', $form_state);
form_set_value($form['maintenance_type'], 'I', $form_state);
```

What is the correct way to use `form_set_value()` to achieve what I want? Am I using the wrong function and there is a different function/method I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$form_state->set('store_value', "value to assign");` to set the hidden form element, and
`$value = $form_state->get('store_value');` to retrieve its value.

Don't use `getValue()` or `setValue()`, because they are for submitted values.

If you are migrating forms from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8, [$form_state is now a classed object](https://www.drupal.org/node/2310411) may help you.